# How much to wait or how long to wait?

Tags: meaning

As I can see both of the ways are correct.

When should I use "How **much** to wait" and when "How **long** to wait"?

Comment: What is your native by the way? Turkish? As you say both of the ways are correct.

Comment: No, but you're close :) @Grizzly

Comment: I know 'ne kadar' means both 'how long' and 'how much' in Turkish so tried my luck by looking at your picture. Gahhh now I really wonder where are you from and the language you speak and what do you use for 'how long' and 'how much'.

Answer (score 2):

If you say 'How much to wait', I'll interpret it in two different ways. Consider these 2 dialogues.

> A) How much to wait? (Asking the price of waiting here)
>
> B) It is 5$ to wait here.

The second dialogue;

> A) Can you wait here?
>
> B) Sure, How much to wait? (Asking How much you will pay me for
>   waiting here)
>
> A) 5$

'How long to wait' is the sentence you mean I believe as both the above dialogues seems weird.

> A) How long to wait ...? (for something to happen, or between this and
>   that)
>
> B) 5 minutes.